# Why 0x4e0 instead of 0x0 in wav file head?

Tags: c, wav, binaryfiles

I have a wav file named "file.wav", and I want to read some specification of the file with a C program. I found the structure of wav file [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/). According to this document, in a normal wav file, the AudioFormat bytes should be 0x1 and 0x0, or the  NumChannels bytes should be (if mono) 0x1 and 0x0; there are lots of similar sections that should look like these.

Now, my C program is very easy: I open the file in binary mode, I seek to the AudioFormat section (the 20th byte), I read two bytes and I put them in a buffer; then  I print to stdin the buffer content.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    void *buf[2];
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("file.wav", "rb");

    fseek(f, 20, SEEK_SET); 
    fread(buf, 1, 2, f);
    printf("example: %#hx %#hx\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
/*the '#' flag stands for the 0x[···] format output, 
the 'h' says that the number is a short integer (2 bytes).*/


    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the second byte instead of being 0x0 is always 0x4e0, and this for every byte which should be 0 (for example for NumChannels or BitPerSamples bytes too). What is the problem?

Comment: Why the heck are you reading bytes into pointers?

Comment: ... and how can a byte be 0x4e0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you were lucky, you would have got compilation warning or crash at runtime. Although I think for this particular case you won't, I don't think what you are doing is actually *undefined behavior*. The core of your problem is that when you declare this:

```
void *buf[2];
```

you are declaring *buf as array 2 of pointer to void*. When you access `buf[0]` you are not reading *bytes* but *pointers*. There is a lot more that could be said to explain what is going on, but I think this would be enough for what you are trying to do:

```
char buf[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

As others has mentioned, you are reading into a pointer array.

Second is the audio format field is 2 bytes.

```
FILE *f;
short afmt;

if((f = fopen("file.wav", "rb")) == NULL)
   err(1, "fopen");
fseek(f, 20, SEEK_SET);
fread(&afmt, sizeof(short), 1, f);
printf("audio format: 0x%hx\n", afmt);
fclose(f);
```